# ARM Cortex-M7 long branch get error "relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31" at compiling time

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m

I'm developing an embedded system with NXP's I.MXRT Series Cortex-M7 chip. I need relocation some C function in RAM(ITCM) while not in Flash. Address of ITCM begin at 0x00000000, Flash begin at 0x60000000. So a function locating at Flash call a function locating at ITCM will perform a long branch. But It gets a compiling error

> (.ARM.exidx.itcm.text+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.itcm.text'

Here is my code

```
__attribute__ ((long_call,section(".itcm.text"),noinline))
int foo(int k)
{
     return k + 1;
}
```

My linkscript

```
MEMORY
{
 /*
 *  SPI Flash 
 *  
 *  
 */
ITCM(xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 128K
DTCM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 256K
RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN =   0x20200000, LENGTH = 256K
FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN =  0x60000000, LENGTH = 4096K
}
 /*************omit***************/
_siitcm = LOADADDR(.itcm.text);
.itcm.text : ALIGN(4)
{
    __itcm_start__ = .;
    *(.itcm.text .itcm.text.*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __itcm_end__ = .;
} >ITCM AT>FLASH
```

Compiler flags are

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb ${FP_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3 -munaligned-access -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding

Linker flags are

> "arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb ${FP_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3 -munaligned-access -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -T ${MEM_LD_FILE} -T ${LIBS_LD_FILE} -T ${SECTIONS_LD_FILE} -nostartfiles -Xlinker -gc-sections -u _printf_float -Wl,-Map=${TARGET_MAP} --specs=nano.specs"

It seems the error occurs when branch address is greater than 0x40000000. So, how to fix this issue?

/*** Second Edition ***/

I have solved the issue by adding a compiler flag -fno-exceptions. But I don't know why?

Comment: use bogus addresses that are near each other, get it to build, see what address it uses and the instruction and that should explain it.

Comment: or actually just look at the object file since it cant link it...

Comment: You may be able to get some insight about the `-fno-exceptions` behavior from the [Exception Handling ABI for the ARM Architecture (ARM IHI 0038B)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0038b/IHI0038B_ehabi.pdf), specifically section 4.4.2 "Relocations" which mentions the use of `R_ARM_PREL31` for offsets. `R_ARM_PREL31`is a 31-bit 2's complement number - note: **not** a 32-bit number. See [ELF for the ARM Architecture (ARM IHI 0044E)](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0044/e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf)

Comment: Maybe it would help if you compile the C functions that go into RAM(ITCM) as C instead of as C++?

Comment: Well, the jump address of 31-bit 2's complement is indeed +- 0x40000000. But it should use a long branch instruction BLX Ri which can jump all 32bit address space according to ARM's manual. In fact, I don't know clearly what is "relocation"? My project contains C and C++ files. The function goes into ITCM is in an extern"C" block. But linker is C++ I think.

Comment: A relocation is how the compiler or linker can represent an address that it doesn't completely know what the actual address will be (because it's in an object file that will be linked later or in an executable that will be loaded at some unknown address). The linker or loader resolves those relocations to fixed addresses.  The unused bit in a `R_ARM_PREL31` is used as a flag in various places; search the document for "prel31" to get an idea - I sure don't know the detailed reasons.

Comment: Finally, another idea (if you want or need to avoid `-fno-exceptions`) is to have your C++ code call a C function that is in the same flash area as the C++ code. Then have that 'normal' C function do nothing but call the one in RAM(ITCM).  That might be enough indirection to break whatever exception handling tracking is occurring.  This is just a guess though.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue. After compiling without the `-fexceptions` build flag, the file compiled with no issue.

Answer (score 2):

The ARM-EABI specifies exceptions veneers are 31bit relative.  Meaning that all C++ that can throw or catch (ie., that with C++ linkage, not -fno-exception) will need to be located in memory no more than 30 bits (plus or minus) from the .ARM-extab and .ARM.exidx sections or the relative offset will be insufficient -- thus the error.

It is likely the ARM-EABI took advantage of the Linux default user space being the lower 31 bits of the 32 bits of the ARM32 address space.

So, look at your memory map.  Is there a stash +-30 bits to place the extab/exidx for greatest coverage of your .text memory (XIP flash, SDRAM, OCRAM)?  Can you restrict (via the linker script) your C++ to just the covered regions?  Can you place non-text (data, bss, etc.) in the out of range memory? (Data and non-C++ and C++-noexception .text accesses are not REL31 -- just C++ exceptions are.)